# Override Role Provider - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

Edit: By Overriding the RoleProvider we were hoping to still use the same methods with our new methods. Such as Roles.GetRolesForUser(int).

```
 string[] myRoles3 = ((PortalRoleProvider) (Roles.Provider)).GetRolesForUser(2);
```

That above code seems a bit excessive ?

I have a class which overrides some members of the RoleProvider and adds new methods. Eg.

```
 public string[] GetRolesForUser(int UserId)
    {
        IEnumerable<Role> RoleList = _Repo.GetRolesForUser(UserId);


        string[] RetVal = new string[] {};

        foreach (var curRole in RoleList)
        {
            RetVal[RetVal.GetUpperBound(0)] = curRole.RoleName;
        }
        return RetVal;
    }
```

Now when I am in the logic of my code I want to write Roles.GetRolesForUser(2) but when i type this, it does seem to see the extra method that I have added. Here is the class declaration and the webconfig.

```
 namespace PortalMVC.Providers
 {
    public class PortalRoleProvider : RoleProvider
    {
```

Web.config

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="PortalRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
         <add name="PortalRoleProvider" type="PortalMVC.Providers.PortalRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Any suggestions why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast your RoleProvider as your actual object type (i.e. PortalRoleProvider) to see the extra functions.  This applies to any time you've extended a standard object but are accessing it as it's super class (Master pages, etc.)

`string[] myRoles3 = ((PortalRoleProvider) (Roles.Provider)).GetRolesForUser(2);`

The above, as you've pointed out in your post, works.  If you need to use this a lot in a section of code, you can create a pointer with the proper type then access the methods from there:

`PortableRoleProvider TempPointer=(PortableRoleProvider)Roles.Provider;`

string[] myRoles3=TempPointer.GetRolesForUser(2);

Comment: Ok this makes sense, can you expand? If I wanted to call the GetRolesForUser(int a) how would I do that?

Comment: "string[] myRoles = new PortalRoleProvider().GetRolesForUser(2);" this seems a bit backwards though since we only want to expand on the current RoleProvider.

Comment: Better yet, use interfaces to decouple the objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the web.config, where you specify the type for the role provider, you might need to add the name of the assembly where the type can be found.  Something like this:

```
<add name="PortalRoleProvider" type="PortalMVC.Providers.PortalRoleProvider, MyAssemblyName" />
```

Comment: I've done this, but this hasnt helped with the above issue. Thanks though.